# Makefile for running docker container with pseudo TTY

Tags: docker, makefile

I have a following Makefile:

```
start: delete-network create-network start-container delete-network

start-container:
    docker run -it --rm --network docky docky bash

create-network:
    docker network create docky

delete-network:
    docker network remove docky 2> /dev/null || true
```

Unfortunately when I call `make start`, `delete-network` task is ignored after I exit from cotainer. How can I execute all tasks?

Comment: Is it actually being ignored, or is it failing in some way that you're suppressing?  (Does deleting `2>/dev/null || true` give you more information?)  Using Make this way can run into a couple of oddities, would a different tool like a shell script work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running the container and cleaning up is the goal, this will do it:

```
start: delete-network create-network start-container

start-container:
    docker run -it --rm --network alpine alpine sh; docker network remove alpine

create-network:
    docker network create alpine

delete-network:
    docker network remove alpine 2> /dev/null || true
```

and a version without duplication:

```
start: create-network start-container delete-network

start-container:
    -docker run -it --rm --network alpine alpine sh

create-network:
    docker network create alpine || true

delete-network: 
    docker network remove alpine 2> /dev/null || true
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to re-use existing make task to avoid duplication.

Comment: @lucas Now that I think of it you could use the same trick as for delete-network and always return true from start container. Then your solution would work and no duplication. Worth trying. I also don’t like duplication …. in general ;)

Comment: how can I always return true from start container? When I try `docker run -it --rm --network docky docky bash || true`, the `|| true` part is passed to the container.

Comment: @Lucas my knowledge of make kind of stops here :) however I added a second version without duplication to the solution

Comment: I've just noticed that you removed duplicated `delete-network` invocation in `start` task. I've learned the hard way that Make does not run the same task again if it's listed more than once on the dependencies list.

Comment: a while ago I came across this tutorial and I still think it is a good source of inspiration: https://makefiletutorial.com/